# How to use *ngFor in ion-item so that each has an individual functionality

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Context: I'm using Firebase Database to store list items. Currently, I am trying to display these list items with an ion-checkbox.

JSON: [image]

Desired functionality: Essentially, when a user clicks the checkbox, the value "checked" should turn to "true" for that INDIVIDUAL BULLET ONLY.

The error: 
When one box is checked, all of the other items in the list get checked off as well. I've been sitting on my butt all week trying to figure this out. How can I fix this?

Code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AddBulletPage } from '../add-bullet/add-bullet';

//Firebase imports
import * as firebase from "firebase";

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

//Observable
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { bullet } from '../../models/bullet.interface';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-clicked-list',
  templateUrl: 'clicked-list.html',
})
export class ClickedListPage {

  bullet = {} as bullet;
  cucumber: boolean;
  selectedItem: any;
  bulletRef: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,) {
    this.selectedItem = navParams.get('list');
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      this.bulletRef = this.db.list(data.uid+'/listItemsof-/'+this.selectedItem.name).valueChanges();
    })
  }

  updateCucumber($key){
    console.log('New state:'+this.cucumber);
    this.selectedItem = this.navParams.get('list');
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      this.selectedItem = this.navParams.get('list');
      var usersRef = firebase.database().ref(data.uid+'/listItemsof-/'+this.selectedItem.name);
      var ref = usersRef.orderByChild('checked').equalTo($key);
      var select = this.selectedItem.name;
      var state = this.cucumber;
      ref.once('value').then(function(snap){
        snap.forEach(function (childSnap) {
          var pkey = childSnap.key;
          console.log(pkey);
          console.log(select);
          firebase.database().ref(data.uid+'/listItemsof-/'+select+'/'+pkey).child("checked").set(state);
          console.log('changed state');
        })
      }); 
    });

  }

}
```

```html
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title class="bar">{{selectedItem.name}}</ion-title>
    <style *ngIf="selectedItem.color=='#ffce4e'">
      .bar {
        background-color: #ffce4e;
      }
    </style>


  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let bullet of bulletRef | async">
      <ion-label>{{bullet.description}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox *ngIf="bullet.checked == true" color="pink" disabled="true" checked="true"></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-checkbox *ngIf="bullet.checked == false" color="pink" [(ngModel)]="cucumber" (ionChange)="updateCucumber(bullet.$key==bullet.description)"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

*I should note that all "bullet"s that are added to the Firebase DB, start out with a "checked" child of "false".

Comment: Did you resolved it?

Comment: @VíctorDaniel Yes, I did eventually. (Forgot I posted this question.) Would you like me to post the solution?

Answer (score 3):

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
<div *ngFor="let bullet of bulletRef">
    <ion-item >
      <ion-label>{{bullet.description}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox *ngIf="bullet.checked == true" color="pink" disabled="true" checked="true"></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-checkbox *ngIf="bullet.checked == false" color="pink" [(ngModel)]="cucumber" (ionChange)="updateCucumber(bullet.$key==bullet.description)"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</div>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Use Like this i think it should work

Comment: Unfortunately, the code isn't working and the same error occurs.

Comment: I changed the code . Please check this i think the problem is with async

Comment: The async is very much required in this case, as otherwise I am not able to display my database data. Without it, the page does not even load.

Answer (score 0):

I think change your html to ng-template then everything ok.

```
<ion-item>
    <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="bulletRef | async">
         <ion-label>{{item.description}}</ion-label>
         <ion-checkbox *ngIf="item.checked == true" color="pink" disabled="true" checked="true"></ion-checkbox>
         <ion-checkbox *ngIf="item.checked == false" color="pink" [(ngModel)]="cucumber" (ionChange)="updateCucumber(item.$key==item.description)"></ion-checkbox>
    </ng-template>
</ion-item>
```